# mysql / php select first and last record for each year there are records in a particular column in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

I have a table of records of wildlife sightings for different animals. Each row in the table is a record card containing columns for the different animals that it is possible to see, plus an ID column and a DateSeen column.

I would like to display the first and last records for each year from the table below where 1 or more of a particular animal has been seen. I need to display the first and last dates for every year including future years as more data is added. The first and last dates shown should be based on URL parameter that selects which column (animal) to query.

How is this done using mySQL select query and PHP?

**TABLE**

```
ID    DateSeen       Lion             Tiger
01    2018-01-01     1                4
02    2018-08-15     2                0
03    2018-09-04     0                2
04    2017-02-02     1                3
05    2017-06-19     2                0 
06    2017-07-24     1                1
07    2017-07-26     0                4
08    2016-01-06     1                1
09    2016-09-17     1                0 
10    2016-09-19     0                4
11    2015-06-11     0                1
12    2015-10-09     1                0
13    2015-10-12     1                0
```

**If the URL parameter = Tiger, results should return**

```
ID    DateSeen (DD-MM-YYYY)       Tiger
01    01-01-2018                  4        = first sighting of Tiger in 2018
03    04-09-2018                  2        = last sighting of Tiger in 2018
04    02-02-2017                  3        = first sighting of Tiger in 2017
06    24-07-2017                  1        = last sighting of Tiger in 2017
08    06-01-2016                  1        = first sighting of Tiger in 2016
10    19-09-2016                  4        = last sighting of Tiger in 2016
11    11-06-2015                  1        = first sighting of Tiger in 2015
11    11-06-2015                  1        = last sighting of Tiger in 2015
```

**If the URL parameter = Lion, results should return**

```
ID    DateSeen (DD-MM-YYYY)      Lion
01    01-01-2018                 1        = first sighting of Lion in 2018
02    15-08-2018                 2        = last sighting of Lion in 2018
04    02-02-2017                 1        = first sighting of Lion in 2017
06    24-07-2017                 1        = last sighting of Lion in 2017
08    06-01-2016                 1        = first sighting of Lion in 2016
09    17-09-2016                 1        = last sighting of Lion in 2016
12    09-10-2015                 1        = first sighting of Lion in 2015
13    12-10-2015                 1        = last sighting of Lion in 2015
```

It doesn't matter if the first and last sightings dates of a particular animal are the same (i.e. Tiger only seen once in 2015 as I need to show that that sighting is a first and last sighting in the results.

The date format in the database is YYYY-MM-DD and I need do display the results with the year formatted to DD-MM-YYYY.

Huge thanks in advance to anyone who can help.
Oh and I'm using PHP (pdo), MySql and PhpMyAdmin. I have over 30K records and 40 animals!
Steve

Comment: I’d suggest you start with the basic principle as explained under https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html - only you will want to GROUP over two columns/values, the animal ID and the year portion of the date. Once you have that, write a second query that does the opposite thing - get the minimum date per animal and year. Throw the two results together using UNION, and maybe apply additional sorting after that.

Comment: Do you really have one column for each animal? And dates stored as varchar?

Comment: Hi Salman, DateSeen column is stored as DATE as I don't need to record time of day, just Day, Month and Year. Any yes, one column for each animal.

Answer (score 0):

Your test data is all from 2018, and assuming that you need entries from table column value for of animal is greater than zero

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               dateseen, 
               lion, 
               year1 
        FROM   table5 t1 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT Substr(dateseen, 1, 4) year1, 
                                  Min(dateseen)          min_dateseen 
                           FROM   table5 
                           WHERE  lion <> 0 
                           GROUP  BY Substr(dateseen, 1, 4)) t2 
                       -- get first and last dateseen for each year  
                       ON t1.dateseen = t2.min_dateseen 
        UNION 
        SELECT id, 
               dateseen, 
               lion, 
               year1 
        FROM   table5 t2 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT Substr(dateseen, 1, 4) year1, 
                                  Max(dateseen)          AS max_dateseen 
                           FROM   table5 
                           WHERE  lion <> 0 
                           GROUP  BY Substr(dateseen, 1, 4)) t3 
                       ON t2.dateseen = t3.max_dateseen) t4 
ORDER  BY year1 DESC, 
          Date_format(dateseen, '%Y-%m-%d') ASC;
```

refer to dbfiddle - [DBFiddleDemo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e8088741dce76c2bf437f0bb21b1971) for complete solution

If your version is 8.0 then you can use CTE which will reduce the number of queries needed.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Vijiy

I tried your code but get an error replacing mytable for 'AnimalRecords' and <param_req_col>  for Tiger but get the following error.

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'min(date) min_date 
                                        FROM     AnimalRecords' at line 9

Comment: Can you try, syntax issue columns were not seperated by comma

Comment: Vijiy? Missing 'AS' in second select statement I think but updated code still errors.

7 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "t3" at position 999)
Unexpected token. (near "t3" at position 999)
" (near "=" at position 1034)
" (near "t3" at position 1035)
" (near "." at position 1037)
" (near "max_date" at position 1038)
"(near ")" at position 1090)

Comment: updated my answer, Can you try again, have not checked for syntax errors

Comment: Vijiy... I get #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias error

Comment: @StevenCheshire - Can you check now, i have corrected for syntax error with the help of dbfiddle

Answer (score 0):

your database scheme very bad, must be such

id, datetime,animal

1, 2018-01-01 15:21:32, Lion(type=enum(Lion,Tiger,etc..)),

But your question

```
SELECT id,Tiger,date_format(DateSeen, '%d-%m-%Y') as dateAlias from your_table where date_format(DateSeen, '%Y-01-01') = DateSeen OR date_format(DateSeen, '%Y-12-31') = DateSeen AND Tiger > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change table structure, this is bad.
After you make good structure you can use query like this:

```
SELECT min(DateSeen) as first, max(DateSeen) as last, animal FROM animals
GROUP BY year(DateSeen)
```

Comment: oh, Steven can use this query with current table structure, just there will be no counts in the result, and first & last seeings would be in one row

Comment: Kristijan Mikulec... how would I select a column, e.g. tiger or lion based on url parameter?

e.g.
SELECT min(DateSeen) as first, max(DateSeen) as last, **<URL Param>** FROM animals
GROUP BY year(DateSeen)

??? would that risk SQL injection??

Comment: SELECT min(DateSeen) as first, max(DateSeen) as last, animal FROM animals WHERE animal = 'lion'
GROUP BY year(DateSeen)

Comment: There is a risk for SQL injection, so you need to use pdo prepared statements